# How to show WAV files on Ubuntu

Tags: sound, file-type, wav

I have some WAV files on my phone and they are not shown on that folder when I open it in nautilus on Ubuntu? What should I do?

Comment: That folder? Shown where, Nautilus, terminal, anywhere else?

Answer (score 1):

your phone is not a usb-storage device that just provides access to the filesystem , it is using MTP which provides selective access to the filesystem on your phone.  This is because the old usb-storage method could lead to corrupt files because it didn't handle the concurrency issues.

It would seem that either WAV is a type of file that is filtered out by MTP or the files in question might be too big. This is a fair assumption for a phone because they typically use compressed audio whereas WAV files are large uncompressed PCM data that is more common in music production.

I found an ftp server app for my android phone and use it over wifi via nautilus, just click the 'Connect to Server' dialog, its less battery efficient but i don't do much file transfer anyway.

Comment: Hi, thanks, actually they are not too big. Can you give me a link to that app or add it to the answer. thank you.

Comment: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=lutey.FTPServer&hl=en_GB